# php74 php-cgi HIGH CPU, cannot redcue it

Tags: php, wordpress

All of a sudden I am experiencing super high CPU 100%.  The only change, updated wordpress and cpanel to the newest version.

/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/bin/php-cgi

The backend / admin or wordpress, extremely sluggish. If I try to edit a post it takes a few seconds for the right sidebar to load.

I am on apache2 on digitalocean.  Running with  8GB of RAM.  Memory is not an issue.  CPU is.  It gets worse if I enable php-fpm.  If I have two sites with ti own, the cpu get's pinned at 100% blocking all request.  The only way to solve is kill the process and then only allow one site to run with php-fpm.  I have no idea where the issue lies.  I reached out to Cpanel support and they also are not sure.  They did find an article about php-fpm and opcache causing issues.  Any idea how to reduce the CPU and get the sites running smoothly again?

Even the error logs are vague. But this was found

```
kill(23988, SIGTERM)                    = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
fcntl(3, F_GETLK, {l_type=F_RDLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=1, l_len=1, l_pid=23988}) = 0
kill(23988, SIGTERM)                    = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
fcntl(3, F_GETLK, {l_type=F_RDLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=1, l_len=1, l_pid=23988}) = 0
kill(23988, SIGTERM)                    = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
fcntl(3, F_GETLK, {l_type=F_RDLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=1, l_len=1, l_pid=23988}) = 0
kill(23988, SIGTERM)                    = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
fcntl(3, F_GETLK, {l_type=F_RDLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=1, l_len=1, l_pid=23988}) = 0
kill(23988, SIGTERM)                    = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
fcntl(3, F_GETLK, {l_type=F_RDLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=1, l_len=1, l_pid=23988}) = 0
kill(23988, SIGTERM)                    = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
fcntl(3, F_GETLK, {l_type=F_RDLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=1, l_len=1, l_pid=23988}) = 0
kill(23988, SIGTERM)                    = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
fcntl(3, F_GETLK, {l_type=F_RDLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=1, l_len=1, l_pid=23988}) = 0
kill(23988, SIGTERM)                    = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
fcntl(3, F_GETLK, {l_type=F_RDLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=1, l_len=1, l_pid=23988}) = 0
kill(23988, SIGTERM)                    = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
fcntl(3, F_GETLK, {l_type=F_RDLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=1, l_len=1, l_pid=23988}) = 0
kill(23988, SIGTERM)                    = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
fcntl(3, F_GETLK, {l_type=F_RDLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=1, l_len=1, l_pid=23988}) = 0
kill(23988, SIGTERM)                    = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

There was similar issue here: https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/8072

But I have no idea if related or not.  All I know it if I turn php-fpm on, all site go down until I kill one.  Only one site can be on php-fpm and the rest off. But the others that are off experience high CPU with php-cgi.  Not to sure what to do.

Thank you.